# When Do I use indexers, and how to know how to write them

Tags: c#

```
// Indexer for the _accountList
public Account this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < _accountList.Length)
            return _accountList[index];
        else
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index is out of range");
    }
}
```

These are some notes I took, and is what we are covering, but after my research I am still hazy on this theory of when and how to use indexers.

My question is simply how and when to know to use an indexer? Is the only point of it to check to see if a statement is true? Where I can read up on indexers more in depth for beginners? And what does the exception on the last line mean?

```
throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index is out of range");
```

What does the `throw` mean? I'm guessing it's stating that if it's not in range then to throw the new instance out of range. Seems cut and dry but when do I know when to use this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is simply how and when to know to use an indexer?

Use an indexer when it's convenient and when it makes sense in terms of acessing an object. For example, if you were implementing a custom list type, you would probably provide an indexer for convenient, clean, list-like access. If you were implementing a class that represents a process, you probably wouldn't implement an indexer, as a process is not obviously a collection of items.

> Is the only point of it to check to see if a statement is true?

No. Not even close. The point is to get and/or set an item in a collection, specified by an index.

> What does the `throw` mean? I'm guessing it's stating that if it's not in range then to throw the new instance out of range. Seems cut and dry but when do I know when to use this exception?

This has less to do with indexers and more to do with exceptions. If you haven't learned about exceptions yet, tackle this when you do. But it's just a boundary check, and it's not the only thing exceptions are used for.

Comment: Ok this helps a ton thx. I have tackled exemptions fe and try catch and if statements along with bool. So I understand certain exemptions deal better with others and certain ones trump others completely depending on the matter. I am thinking more clearly about the ex now so thx. I like this answer however and I am now glad I have asked this topic. Is this a proper way of asking a q's on this site as I am a noob here.

Answer (score 1):

Indexers are used as a shorthand way of accessing an element in a collection typically by index or key.

In your example, the indexer allows you to get the `Account` at the specified `index`. The logic checks to make sure the value of `index` is within the range of items in the collection.

So for example, if there are only 2 `Account`s in the collection, and you ask for the `Account` at index 3, you are asking for an item that does not exist. Hence the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: as in the way of class.field?? right is that what you mean because that is what I was aware of. So am I overthinking it?